# Send feedback to the user for a long running operation in Grails?

Tags: grails

I have a long running operation in my Grails application. My first solution is simply to perform the operation in the controller and let the user wait until the action is finished. This is not an acceptable solution, I want to show the user the progress of the action. The progress is simply text. The action can take from 10 seconds to roughly 30 minutes.

How can I show the progress to the user for my long running action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you might want to try the [Executor plugin](https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor) so you can run the job in the background.  This works quite well.

Then I guess you have 2 options.  Have the browser poll the server via Ajax for an update (as Tim pointed out the JProgress plugin would do something like this for you) or get even more bleeding edge and consider [HTML5 WebWorkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) for a kind of server push approach.  WebWorkers are not available in

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like a Task or Job domain class with a field percentageComplete. The controller will create and save the Task or Job and then spawn a new thread to execute it. Perhaps place the execution code in a service.

It will be up to your execution code to update the Task or Job's percentageComplete field as it completes its task. Then you can poll the job (via ajax) to see how the job is progressing.

Note: determining that percentage which is complete is very much to up to your specific code. You will probably have to just come up with a best guess based on the knowledge you have. Even for an operation where it is obvious how to determine percentage complete (like a file download), it is not certain (network issues, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you determin the state of your progress? Let's say in percent?
I would create the long operation as a quarz job (background) and query the state of job/ long running progress via ajax.

Comment: No, I only get a textual log of the progress. I don't have any percentage. Basically I would like to show this text log to the user. I guess I need to use a separate thread and a remote Ajax function. But I don't know the overall process for doing this.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think using quartz jobs is appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

The [JProgress plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jprogress) might help, but I've never tried it out...